# How i detemine Button (x,y) cords in Layout?

Tags: android

I Have this simple Code:

```
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    bottom = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button close = new Button(this);
    close.setText("Close");
    bottom.addView(close);
    layout.addView(bottom);
    setContentView(layout);
```

- How can i put my button at the bottom of the window i prefer to determine the x,y cords  but any solution will be good.
  since the absoluteLayout is deprecated i tried using the Relativelayout as the api adviced with no succes.
- i'm not using XML at all is that a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set LayoutParametrs (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) to your elements. And don't forget to set LayoutParams to parent view.

> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>
> lp.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
>
> button.setLayoutParams(lp)